# Socket not printing any packets

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

## Issue

I am trying to read packets with socket, but when I run the program even with the appropriate permissions nothing prints to the terminal. I have tested this on Mac OSX 12.5 and Windows 10 but neither work.

## Code

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP) 

while True:
    print(s.recvfrom(65565))

# command to run: sudo python3 main.py
```

I'm not sure what is happening and any help is appreciated!

Comment: You haven't connected the socket to anything.

Comment: @quamrana I didn't think of that lol. I'm still learning how to use socket but this helps!